# how to select for a value that doesn't exist on another table that has a many to one relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table A, that has a multitude of attributes as well as an id field and a names field, and table b that has id field and another names field. The Id field is not unique per record.  What I want to do is select for the records in table A, that have no match in table B.  For example:

```
Table A            |  Table B
ID  Name    meat   |  ID   Name
1   James   chicken|  1    James
1   Ted     steak  |  1    Ted
1   Johnson steak  |  1    Frank
                   |  1    Floren
2   Rebecca fish   |  2    Rebecca
2   Katrina chicken|  2    Katrina
2   Floren  lamb   |  2    Tara
2   Floren  fish   |
2   Floren  steak  |
2   Tara    fish   |
```

So as you can see, there is overlap between the two tables.  What I would like to get as a result is all records where the name in table A is NOT present anywhere in Table B when joined by the ID field.  The result should look like:

```
Table A            |  
ID  Name    meat   |  
1   Johnson steak  | 
2   Floren  lamb   | 
2   Floren  fish   |
2   Floren  steak  |
```

edit: there can be cases of name overlap across the IDs.  So for example if an name is in a different ID on Table B, then I'd still need it returned if its in Table A.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use minus  and the use this as subqoery for join with table_a

```
select * from table_a 
inner join ( 
  select name 
  from  table_a
  minus 
  select name 
  from  table_b

  ) t on t.name  = table_a.name
```

Comment: Im not sure this will work, In my real data, some of the names are in the other ID field also. Thats why i think a join on the id field is necassary. I'll modify the table B in the above

Comment: ... in my answer    the join is on the name  ..  in your original question you want the rows where the name in table a are not in table b

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.name = a.name);
```

If the `id`s need to match as well, just add them in to the correlation condition:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.id = a.id and b.name = a.name
                 );
```

Comment: Im not sure this will work, In my real data, some of the names are in the other ID field also.  Thats why i think a join on the id field is necassary.  I'll modify the table B in the above

Comment: @user7002207 . . . If you want to filter out rows where both `id` and `name` then add that condition to the correlation condition.